# Insert character at cursor position datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How to insert the character GG at the mouse cursor position of datagridview cell when I press F9, where the cursor may be in any position?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I have tried for text box  :- Dim index As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(index, "GG")

Comment: Aha so you want to put a character where the text cursor is, not where the mouse is currently positioned. It was a bit unclear. Try to see if you can learn how to get the textbox out of the textbox cell. Then the action should be the same.

Comment: Thanks I got IT.....Dim c As Control = Me.dgvDetail.EditingControl
                If c IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
                    selectionStart = CType(c, TextBox).SelectionStart
                End If

                Dim text As String = CStr(Me.dgvDetail.CurrentCell.Value)
                Me.dgvDetail.CurrentCell.Value = text.Insert(selectionStart, "GG")

Comment: Brilliant. Kudos for figuring it out yourself instead of just waiting for someone to fill in the blanks. Good job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim c As Control = Me.dgvDetail.EditingControl 
If c IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
   selectionStart = CType(c, TextBox).SelectionStart 
End If Dim text As String = CStr(Me.dgvDetail.CurrentCell.Value)
Me.dgvDetail.CurrentCell.Value = text.Insert(selectionStart, "GG")
```

Comment: I suggest you set selectionStart to +2 after adding GG so that you can continue typing after inserting GG.